# how to wrap text inside the screen?

Tags: react-native

hi there i have a small problem i dont know why my text dont want to be wrapped but the problem the same code work for me in other screen but in the screen below dont want to work ?
here is some screenshot from my phone
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhx5r.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkigk.png)

and this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Part = (props) => (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginHorizontal: 20, marginVertical: 10 }}>
      <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}>-</Text>
      <View>
          <Text style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>{props.name}</Text>
          {props.adress !== null ? <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text>Adresse : </Text>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} >
              <Text style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>{props.adress}</Text>
              </View>
          </View> : null }
          {props.tel !== null ? <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text>Tél : </Text>
              <View>
                  {props.tel.map((tel) => (
                          <Text>{tel}</Text>
                      )
                  ) }
              </View>
          </View> : null }
          {props.fax !== null ? <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text>Fax : </Text>
              <View>
                  {props.fax.map((fax) => (<Text>{fax}</Text>))}
              </View>
          </View> : null}
      </View>
    </View>
 );


export default Part;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give width in percentage Like

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'' }}>
          <Text>Adresse : </Text>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',width:'50% }} >
          <Text style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>{props.adress}</Text>
          </View>
```

Comment: thank you it's worked but the problem the look isnt well and every adress has it own size

Comment: you have to give width in order to wrap content. you can make your own dynamic function like this  `${text.length <15 ? 15: 30 }%`